# Why do fixed elements slow down scrolling in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, css-position

Why do elements with the CSS `position: fixed` applied to them cause Firefox to eat 100% CPU when scrolling the page they are in? And are there any workarounds?

I've noticed this behavior on a few sites, for example the notification bar at the top of the page on StackOverflow. I'm using Linux in case that matters.

Answer (score 6):

This is [bug #201307](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201307).

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug reported in [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201307)

Apparently a work-around (with mixed reports of success..) is to [disable smooth-scrolling](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=6a1b84b5381937fac2f478508203098e&p=3675924&postcount=6)

> Just disable smooth scrolling in Edit > Preferences > Advanced.

Answer (score 2):

As already stated, this is bug [#201307](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201307). The workaround is to disable smooth scrolling:

Edit -> Prefrences -> Advanced -> General tab -> uncheck "Use smooth scrolling"

Answer (score 1):

This website has a fixed element "First time at Stack Overflow? Check out the FAQ!", and it's slow as hell in firefox. Works better with Opera and Chrome though.
FF3, Windows XP, ATI.

Answer (score 1):

it eats CPU because the browser has to repaint the entire viewport every scroll change rather than just the newly visible area

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that there's a direct link here? Have you created a static HTML page with fixed elements to verify your theory? Given how widely these CSS properties are used, I'd think someone else would have noticed it by now, whatever browser/OS you're running.