# Position: fixed Background DIV with images makes scrolling slow: How to make conditional CSS rules for browser-compatibility?

Tags: html, css, browser, background, cross-browser

A known old known problem is that various old browsers both IE 7 (perhaps also IE 8) and FireFox 3.0 ~ 3.6, are the experiencing of very SLOW scrolling down through a webpage whenever a background image `img` or `div` with an image has the `position: fixed;` property.

Having built a site with this feature I noticed that in IE 7 (maybe 8 too) that had a terribly sluggish scrolling experience ruing the good enjoyment of the entire website. All other JQuery effects were also not smooth anymore. Now, as soon as I commented the `position: fixed;` property of the background image div:img, everything becomes good again.

```
<html><head>
img#bg {
/*  position:fixed;*/
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:auto;
    min-height:100%; /* proportionally fit height (eg panorama images)  */
    width: 100%;
    z-index:-2;
}
</head>
<body><img src="background.jpg" id="bg"/></body>
</html>
```

**Q1: How to make that line conditional?** Users with IE7 or IE8 `/*position:fixed;*/` and users with IE9 or FF4 `position:fixed`

**Q2: Could anything in my css have triggered the bug except `position: fixed?`** for example should `img#bg` be written differently?

Some links: [MozzilaZine](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=653791&start=195), [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67588/why-do-fixed-elements-slow-down-scrolling-in-firefox), [LinDesk](http://lindesk.com/2009/05/slow-scrolling-in-firefox-in-pages-with-fixed-backgrounds/)

Thanks very much for your suggestions and ideas on this browserbug. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Q1: How to make that line conditional?**

For IE older than version 9 there's always a conditional comment override:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<style>img#bg { position: absolute; }</style>
<![endif]-->
```

For Firefox, one way would be to find some hack that distinguishes version 4 from its predecessors, which I can't really think of right now.

> **Q2: Could anything in my css have triggered the bug except `position: fixed?`**

That and the fact that it's an image. But mostly the fixed positioning. This also happens if you used a background image with `background-attachment: fixed`, and is a well-known performance issue on those browsers.

Comment: And I really don't advocate using hacks, especially not for a standards-compliant browser like Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

> #### Q1: How to make that line conditional?

If you'd rather not to use conditional comments (per BoltClock's reply), a summary of browser-specific CSS hacks can be found on [Paul Irish's site](http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/).

> #### Q2: Could anything in my css have triggered the bug except `position: fixed`?

**Short answer:** Yes, but probably none as much as `position: fixed`. If removing it fixes your issue, it's your biggest problem.

**Slightly longer answer:** `box-shadow` has been shown to cause performance issues. So will IE's proprietary filters. Inefficient selectors are sometimes mentioned, but it's debatable whether they have a large effect.

To profile your code, use the [CSS Stress Test bookmarklet](https://github.com/andyedinborough/stress-css) to drill down on exactly which selectors are causing your browser trouble. It's great!