# Firefox stalls displaying pages with code in Stackoverflow or github, while chromium doesn't

Tags: firefox, github, chromium

I'm running Ubuntu-16.04.6 LTS on NVIDIA TX2 (L4T R28.2.0).
When using firefox(66.0.2), I'm experiencing long stalls (sometimes Ubuntu gets dark) when browsing pages with code in stackoverflow or github.

With firefox when it lags I can see a CPU at 100% with htop.
It doesn't happen with chromium (73.0.3683.86).

Does anyone know this issue, and further a fix or workaround ?

Comment: Use the Developer Tools Network tab to see what requests are stalling.

Comment: Using the console, I can see a lot of messages : Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘https://api.github.com/_private/browser/stats’. (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’)

Comment: And also these (sorry I'm not familiar with this):  The resource at “https://assets.adobedtm.com/b92787824f2e0e9b68dc2e993f9bd995339fe417/satelliteLib-7ba51e58dc61bcb0e9311aadd02a0108ab24cc6c.js” was blocked because content blocking is enabled.[Learn More] 1
Checking if the user is logged in 1:78:6
checkSSOLogin has been deprecated. Please remove it from your code dz-auth.js:134:5
ReferenceError: eventer is not defined[Learn More] 1:106:5
The resource at “https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js” was blocked because content blocking is enabled.[Learn More] 1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not the place for problems with StackOverflow. Please re-post to https://meta.stackoverflow.com instead.

Comment: Well these error messages were seen on a github page...not only on stackoverflow. However I understand this is not so clear reporting, mainly because I'm not familiar with browser tools nor familiar with stackoverflow formatting. I'd give this topic a try for another answer, but thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: This is off-topic here, but it doesn't belong on Meta. It belongs on [su].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems it is a known bug...
[Why do fixed elements slow down scrolling in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67588/why-do-fixed-elements-slow-down-scrolling-in-firefox?rq=1)

The workaround is to disable smooth scrolling in firefox preferences.